# Javascript Closures with ReactJS and FileReader API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I am trying to handle multiple image uploads and display them to the user before the form is submitted.

I am having trouble getting all of the images that are uploaded to be displayed.  No matter how many images are uploaded only the last image is displayed.

I have read lots of answers on StackOverflow regarding javascript closures but they only seem to deal with the index value in a loop being preserved.

I am not sure how to get this to display all the images that are uploaded.

```
class ImageDisplayBlock extends Component {
    render(){
        var counter = 0;
        let pictureList = this.props.pictures.map(function(i){
           return <img src={i} style={this.props.styles} key={counter++} alt="image" />
        }.bind(this));
        return(<div>{pictureList}</div>);
    }
}

class ImageUploadBlock extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            pictures    : [],
            imgRes      : null
        };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleImage = this.handleImage.bind(this);
        this.handleImageHelper = this.handleImageHelper.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.setDisplay();
    }

    handleImageHelper(data){        

        this.setState(({pictures})=> ({ pictures:pictures.concat(data)}));

        this.setState({
            //pictures    : this.state.pictures.concat(data),    
            imgRes      : true //flag to allow component to be displayed
        });
    }


    handleImage(event){        
        var f           = event.target.files;

        for(var key in f){

            if(!f.hasOwnProperty(key)){ continue; }

            var fReader = new FileReader();
            fReader.readAsDataURL(f[key]);


            fReader.onloadend = function(){
                this.handleImageHelper(fReader.result);
            }.bind(this);
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {this.state.imgRes && <ImageDisplayBlock 
                                    pictures={this.state.pictures} 
                                    styles={{"maxWidth":"100px"}}
                                    />}

                <label htmlFor="file">select an image</label>
                <br />                                        
                <input 
                    onChange={this.handleImage} 
                    type="file" multiple 
                    id="file" 
                />
                <a onClick={this.handleClick} href="">close</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Any help would be truly appreciated as I have spent for hours trying to resolve this bug.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So what you are doing here is updating state with previous state. So instead of passing `this.state.pictures` to `handleImageHelper`, please pass the loaded image only, and add it using `this.setState(({pics})=> ({ pics:pics.concat(img)}))`

`setState` allows to be called with a func and it will get passed the previous state.

Comment: It would help to see the `render` method too. If fixing the problem with mutating state doesn't help, check that you are setting the `key` prop wherever you are looping over the images in your `render` method.

Comment: @BrettPeters I have added the full code and also a unique value is being given to the key prop

Comment: Thanks for your input I did implement what you suggested but unfortunately I am still getting the same bug.

Comment: Like Brett Peters said, please use a reasonable key value, the `src` value is better than a counter which is incremented